# Copying Twilio MMS Media files to my server

Tags: twilio, mms, twilio-php

I have an API end point set up on my server for Twilio to notify my server when an SMS/MMS is received.

Up until about 2 weeks ago, I was able to copy the media files of an MMS to my server using the PHP Copy function:

```
copy($sourceFile, $destinationFolder.$destinationFileName);
```

Where

`$sourceFile = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC000000001/Messages/MM000000001/Media/ME000000001'`

However, now, instead of getting the media file, I'm getting XML that describes the file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse>
<Media>
<Sid/>
<AccountSid>AC000000001</AccountSid>
<ParentSid/>
<ContentType/>
<DateCreated>Thu, 04 Apr 2019 15:31:30 +0000</DateCreated>
<DateUpdated>Thu, 04 Apr 2019 15:31:30 +0000</DateUpdated>
<Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC000000001/Messages/MM000000001/Media/ME000000001</Uri>
</Media>
</TwilioResponse>
```

Nothing has changed in my code and I can't find any documentation suggesting that Twilio was changing how things work.

I tried changing to a curl request and I get the same result. I also tried using the Twilio PHP SDK and following this documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource#default-content-type

Does anyone have some insight as to what is happening/what changed and how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `"ME000000001"` from

`$sourceFile = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC000000001/Messages/MM000000001/Media/ME000000001'`

and then at the `"ME000000001"` from the XML response

`<Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC000000001/Messages/MM000000001/Media/ME000000001</Uri>`

they are different.

In fact for a message with, let's say 3 media attachments, the XML response will look something like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse>
    <MediaList end="2" firstpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media?Pag...>
        <Media>
            <Sid>ME...92c</Sid>
            <AccountSid>AC...3e4</AccountSid>
            <ParentSid>MM...e3d</ParentSid>
            <ContentType>image/jpeg</ContentType>
            <DateCreated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateCreated>
            <DateUpdated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateUpdated>
            <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...3e4/Messages/MM.../Media/ME...92c</Uri>
        </Media>
        <Media>
            <Sid>ME...4ac</Sid>
            <AccountSid>AC...3e4</AccountSid>
            <ParentSid>MM...e3d</ParentSid>
            <ContentType>image/jpeg</ContentType>
            <DateCreated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateCreated>
            <DateUpdated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateUpdated>
            <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...4ac</Uri>
        </Media>
        <Media>
            <Sid>ME...048</Sid>
            <AccountSid>AC...3e4</AccountSid>
            <ParentSid>MM...e3d</ParentSid>
            <ContentType>image/jpeg</ContentType>
            <DateCreated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateCreated>
            <DateUpdated>Tue, 09 Apr 2019 20:06:33 +0000</DateUpdated>
            <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...048</Uri>
        </Media>
    </MediaList>
</TwilioResponse>
```

So, ***you'll find the media at the address in `<Uri>...</Uri>`*** (of course prepend with `https://api.twilio.com`).

---

Observe how the three Uris are different because they point to different media attached to the same message.

```
<Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...92c</Uri>

<Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...4ac</Uri>

<Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC.../Messages/MM.../Media/ME...048</Uri>
```

Comment: thanks, however in my case they are not different... If I load this URL in a web browser, it redirects to the image:
`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...5a93/Messages/MM...6902/Media/ME...6988`
How ever if I try to use PHP to retrieve/copy that file, it produces the XML above with this URI:
`/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...5a93/Messages/MM...6902/Media/ME...6988`
I checked and double checked and the URI is the same as what I'm calling.

Comment: try with a message and attach 2 media to it, your XML should point to two media files, if loaded in browser the uris will redirect to amazon storage

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.